# Distribute values over value-range tiers

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: a list of Total Sales Per Employee, and a list of Compensation Tiers

```
Employee Sales  |   Comp Tiers
==============  |   ===================
EmpID  Sales    |   TierID MaxAmt  Rate
  1    12000    |     1     10000   20%  --  Up to $10k sales  compensated at 20%
  2    17000    |     2     15000   25%  --The next $5k sales  compensated at 25%
  3    23000    |     3     20000   30%  --The next $5k sales  compensated at 30%
  4    31000    |     4     25000   40%  --The next $5k sales  compensated at 40%
                |     5     99999   50%  --Any remaining sales compensated at 50%
```

Based on these inputs, I need to split each employee's Sales over each Tier based on each tier's MaxAmt value to calculate compensation rates at each tier. Further, I don't want to hard-code calculations for each tier as the number of tiers may change over time. (On second thought, I don't mind hard-coding, as long as it can handle UP-TO 5 tiers. Sounds fair?)

Desired Output:

```
EmpID  Sales  TierID  TierAmt  Rate   Net
=========================================
  1    12000    1      10000    20%  2000
  1    12000    2       2000    25%   500
  2    17000    1      10000    20%  2000
  2    17000    2       5000    25%  1250
  2    17000    3       2000    30%   600
  3    23000    1      10000    20%  2000
  3    23000    2       5000    25%  1250
  3    23000    3       5000    30%  1500
  3    23000    4       3000    40%  1200
  4    31000    1      10000    20%  2000
  4    31000    2       5000    25%  1250
  4    31000    3       5000    30%  1500
  4    31000    4       5000    40%  2000
  4    31000    5       6000    50%  3000
```

I'm not unskilled with SQL, but I can't even fathom an appropriate strategy. Any ideas? Changes to table structure are permissible if it helps achieve the goal.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79161/2/0)

Comment: I'm thinking a Recursive CTE could somehow iterate through each Tier to make the calculation. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Beth's suggestion as a jumping-off point, I worked my way through the rest to come up with a workable solution. It starts with a CROSS JOIN to show all possible combinations of Sales and Tiers, filters out those with Sales out of range of their matched Tier, and uses a Recursive CTE to work through each Tier's calculation using the prior Tier results.

```
;WITH 
  /* CROSS JOIN Sales and Tiers, and then        ***/
 /** filter to only relevant Tiers for each Emp. **/
/*** Also include Prior Tier [MaxAmt] value.     */
combos AS
(   SELECT      s.EmpID,s.Sales,t.TierID,
                [MaxAmt-1]  = t0.MaxAmt,
                [MaxAmt]    =  t.MaxAmt
    FROM        EmpSales s 
    CROSS JOIN  CompTiers t
    LEFT JOIN   CompTiers t0 ON t0.TierID = t.TierID-1 --Prior Tier
    WHERE       s.Sales > ISNULL(t0.MaxAmt,0) --Filter out irrelevant Tiers given Sales
),

cte AS
 /* Calculate Tier1 Sales, then use Recursive CTE       **/
/** to calculate other Tiers based on prior Tier values */
(   SELECT      c.*,
                TierAmt = CAST(CASE 
                    WHEN c.Sales > c.[MaxAmt] 
                    THEN c.[MaxAmt] 
                    ELSE c.Sales END AS MONEY)
    FROM        combos c
    WHERE       c.TierID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      c.*,
                TierAmt = CAST(CASE 
                    WHEN c.Sales > c.[MaxAmt] 
                    THEN c.[MaxAmt]-ISNULL(c.[MaxAmt-1],0.0)
                    ELSE c.Sales-ISNULL(c.[MaxAmt-1],0) END AS MONEY)
    FROM        cte
    JOIN        combos c ON c.EmpID = cte.EmpID 
    WHERE       c.TierID = cte.TierID+1
)

 /* Combine [TierAmt] and [Rate] at each Tier */
/** to calculate Net Pay amount.            **/
SELECT      cte.EmpID,cte.Sales,cte.TierID,cte.TierAmt,
            t.Rate,
            Net = t.Rate * cte.TierAmt
FROM        cte
LEFT JOIN   CompTiers t ON t.TierID = cte.TierID
ORDER BY    EmpID,TierID
```

I invite feedback, enhancements, and alternatives.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79161/3/0)

Answer (score 4):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @EmpSales TABLE
(
    EmpID INT,
    Sales INT
)

INSERT INTO @EmpSales
VALUES
( 1, 12000 ),
( 2, 17000 ),
( 3, 23000 ),
( 4, 31000 );

DECLARE @CompTiers TABLE
(
    TierID INT,
    MaxAmount INT,
    Rate DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @CompTiers
VALUES
( 1, 10000, .20 ),
( 2, 15000, .25 ),
( 3, 20000, .30 ),
( 4, 25000, .40 ),
( 5, 99999, .50 );
```

Here I make a CTE to find all of the tiers and the previous (to get the top and bottom of the tier)

```
WITH Tiers AS
(
    SELECT 
        n.TierID,
        n.MaxAmount,
        n.Rate,
        ISNULL(p.MaxAmount, 0) PrevAmount
    FROM @CompTiers n
    LEFT JOIN @CompTiers p
        ON p.TierID = n.TierID - 1
),
```

Lets take the tier CTE and cross join it against the sales picking only the tiers where the sales is greater than the prevamount (bottom of the tier).

```
SalesComp AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @EmpSales e
    CROSS JOIN Tiers c
    WHERE Sales > PrevAmount
)
```

Now that we have the data matched up, just clean it up with some cases:

```
SELECT 
    s.EmpID,
    s.Sales,
    s.TierID,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.Sales > s.MaxAmount THEN s.MaxAmount - s.PrevAmount 
        ELSE s.Sales - s.PrevAmount 
    END TierAmount,
    s.Rate,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.Sales > s.MaxAmount THEN (s.MaxAmount - s.PrevAmount) * s.Rate
        ELSE (s.Sales - s.PrevAmount) * s.Rate
    END Net
FROM SalesComp s
ORDER BY EmpID, TierID
```

Here is the output:

```
EmpID   Sales   TierID  TierAmount  Rate    Net
1   12000   1   10000   0.20    2000.00
1   12000   2   2000    0.25    500.00
2   17000   1   10000   0.20    2000.00
2   17000   2   5000    0.25    1250.00
2   17000   3   2000    0.30    600.00
3   23000   1   10000   0.20    2000.00
3   23000   2   5000    0.25    1250.00
3   23000   3   5000    0.30    1500.00
3   23000   4   3000    0.40    1200.00
4   31000   1   10000   0.20    2000.00
4   31000   2   5000    0.25    1250.00
4   31000   3   5000    0.30    1500.00
4   31000   4   5000    0.40    2000.00
4   31000   5   6000    0.50    3000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind [the following query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79161/7) happens to be same as the one in [Kevin Cook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046927/297408) and the two solutions differ mainly by syntax:

```
WITH TierRanges AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    MinAmt = LAG(MaxAmt, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY MaxAmt)
  FROM
    CompTiers
)
SELECT
  s.EmpID,
  s.Sales,
  t.TierID,
  x.TierAmt,
  t.Rate,
  Net = x.TierAmt * t.Rate
FROM
  EmpSales AS s
INNER JOIN
  TierRanges AS t ON s.Sales > t.MinAmt
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN s.Sales > t.MaxAmt THEN t.MaxAmt ELSE s.Sales END - t.MinAmt
) AS x (TierAmt)
ORDER BY
  s.EmpID,
  t.TierID
;
```

The `TierRanges` CTE "enhances" the `CompTiers` row set with a `MinAmt` column to form a tier range together with `MaxAmt`, `MinAmt` being the previous tier's `MaxAmt` value (or 0, for the first tier). This can be considered a direct equivalent of the other answer's `Tiers` CTE, but you can see that here the [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function is used instead of a self-join, and the former is likely to work faster than the latter.

The main query joins every row in `EmpSales` with every row in `TierRanges` where `EmpSales.Sales` exceeds `TierRanges.MinAmt`. (In the other answer this part is implemented separately from the main query as another CTE, `SalesComp`.) To get the tier amount, it subtracts the `MinAmt` value from either `Sales` or `MaxAmt`, depending on which one is lesser. Because the tier amount is needed twice in the query (once for the output as is and the second time to get `Net`), CROSS APPLY is used to avoid repetition of code.

Because of LAG, SQL Server 2012 is the minimum version required to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

try using a full outer (cross) join between the tables as long as the sales amount is less than or equal to the tier max amount

Comment: This isn't the whole solution naturally, but it was the first step I needed to figure out the rest. Thanks